Combine 2 tables and create new rows if needed
I have 2 tables with a column in common. I want to combine both tables but the common column doesn't have the same exact values in both tables.
Table1:
Rate      |  Age
0-4       |  <6.0
5-6       |  6.0
7-8       |  6.3
9-10      |  <6.6
11-12     |  6.9
13-14     |  7.0
15-16     |  7.3
17-18     |  7.6
19-20     |  7.9
21        |  8.0
22-23     |  8.3
24-25     |  8.6
26        |  8.9
27        |  9.0
28        |  9.3
29        |  9.6
30        |  9.9
31        |  10.0
32        |  10.3
33        |  10.6
34        |  10.9
35        |  11.0
36        |  11.3
37        |  11.6
38        |  11.9
39        |  12.0
40        |  12.3
41        |  12.6
42        |  12.9
43        |  13.0
44        |  13.3
45        |  13.6
46        |  13.9
47        |  14.6
48        |  15.0
49        |  15.3
50        |  15.6
51        |  16.0
52        |  16.6
53        |  17.0
54        |  17.3
55        |  17.6
56        |  18.0
57-80     | >18.0

Table2:
Rate  |  Grade
0-7   |  <1.0
7-8   |  1
9-11  |  1.2
12-13 |  1.4
14-16 |  1.7
17-18 |  2
19-20 |  2.2
21    |  2.4
22-23 |  2.7
24-25 |  3
26    |  3.2
27    |  3.4
28    |  3.7
29    |  4
30    |  4.2
31    |  4.4
32    |  4.7
33-34 |  5
35    |  5.2
36    |  5.4
37    |  5.7
38    |  6
39    |  6.2
40    |  6.4
41    |  6.7
42    |  7
43    |  7.4
44    |  7.7
45    |  8
46    |  8.2
47    |  8.4
48    |  9
49    |  9.2
50    |  9.4
51    |  10.2
52    |  10.4
53    |  11
54    |  11.4
55    |  12
56    |  12.4
57-80 |  13

The newly generated table would have 3 columns (Rate, Age, Grade).
I tried the following script:
import pandas as pd

# Read tables into DataFrames
table1 = pd.read_excel('table1.xlsx')
table2 = pd.read_excel('table2.xlsx')

# Merge tables on 'Rate' column with outer join
merged_table = pd.merge(table1, table2, on='Rate', how='outer')

# Print or save merged table
merged_table.to_excel('merged.xlsx')

The output of this script is not what was expected:
    Rate    Age     Grade
0   21      8       2.4
1   26      8.9     3.2
2   27      9       3.4
3   28      9.3     3.7
4   29      9.6     4
5   30      9.9     4.2
6   31      10      4.4
7   32      10.3    4.7
8   33      10.6    
9   34      10.9    
10  35      11      5.2
11  36      11.3    5.4
12  37      11.6    5.7
13  38      11.9    6
14  39      12      6.2
15  40      12.3    6.4
16  41      12.6    6.7
17  42      12.9    7
18  43      13      7.4
19  44      13.3    7.7
20  45      13.6    8
21  46      13.9    8.2
22  47      14.6    8.4
23  48      15      9
24  49      15.3    9.2
25  50      15.6    9.4
26  51      16      10.2
27  52      16.6    10.4
28  53      17      11
29  54      17.3    11.4
30  55      17.6    12
31  56      18      12.4
32  0-4     <6.0    
33  0-7     <1.0
34  11-12   6.9 
35  12-13           1.4
36  13-14   7   
37  14-16           1.7
38  15-16   7.3 
39  17-18   7.6     2
40  19-20   7.9     2.2
41  22-23   8.3     2.7
42  24-25   8.6     3
43  33-34           5
44  5-6 6   
45  56-80   >18.0   13
46  7-8     6.3     1
47  9-10    6.6 
48  9-11            1.2
49          14      7.2
50          14      8.7
51          14      9.7
52          14      10
53          14      10.7
54          14      11.2
55          14      11.7
56          14      12.2
57          14      12.7
58          14.3    7.2
59          14.3    8.7
60          14.3    9.7
61          14.3    10
62          14.3    10.7
63          14.3    11.2
64          14.3    11.7
65          14.3    12.2
66          14.3    12.7
67          14.9    7.2
68          14.9    8.7
69          14.9    9.7
70          14.9    10
71          14.9    10.7
72          14.9    11.2
73          14.9    11.7
74          14.9    12.2
75          14.9    12.7
76          15.9    7.2
77          15.9    8.7
78          15.9    9.7
79          15.9    10
80          15.9    10.7
81          15.9    11.2
82          15.9    11.7
83          15.9    12.2
84          15.9    12.7
85          16.3    7.2
86          16.3    8.7
87          16.3    9.7
88          16.3    10
89          16.3    10.7
90          16.3    11.2
91          16.3    11.7
92          16.3    12.2
93          16.3    12.7
94          16.9    7.2
95          16.9    8.7
96          16.9    9.7
97          16.9    10
98          16.9    10.7
99          16.9    11.2
100         16.9    11.7
101         16.9    12.2
102         16.9    12.7
103         17.9    7.2
104         17.9    8.7
105         17.9    9.7
106         17.9    10
107         17.9    10.7
108         17.9    11.2
109         17.9    11.7
110         17.9    12.2
111         17.9    12.7

The desired output:
Rate    |    Age     |    Grade
0-4     |    <6.0    |    <1.0
5-6     |    6.0     |    <1.0
7-8     |    6.3     |    1
..      |    ..      |    ..

Example for testing:
import pandas as pd

table1 = pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['0-4', '5-6', '7-8', '9-10', '11-12', '13-14'], 
                        'Age': ['<6.0', '6.0', '6.3', '6.6', '6.9', '7.0']})
table2 = pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['0-7', '7-8', '9-11', '12-13', '14-16', '17-18'], 
                        'Grade': ['<1.0', '1', '1.2', '1.4', '1.7', '2']})

merged_table = pd.merge(table1, table2, on='Rate', how='outer')
merged_table.sort_values('Rate').to_excel('merged1.xlsx')

The output from that example:
    Rate    Age     Grade
0   0-4     <6.0    
1   0-7             <1.0
2   11-12   6.9 
3   12-13           1.4
4   13-14   7.0 
5   14-16           1.7
6   17-18           2
7   5-6     6.0 
8   7-8     6.3     1
9   9-10    6.6 
10  9-11            1.2

The desired output of that example:
    Rate    Age     Grade
0   0-4     <6.0    <1.0
1   5-6     6.0     <1.0    
2   7-8     6.3     1       
9   9-10    6.6     1.2 
2   11-12   6.9     1.4
4   13-14   7.0     1.7
5   15-16   7.3     1.7
6   17-18   7.6     2

So each row has values for the 3 columns.
Is that possible with pandas or other modules/libraries?

I would use .sort_values("Rate") in your example on the merged table, to be sure it does not work. Plus, provide a minimal reproducible example. Namely, extract the first 5 rows, for instance, and show the result. If it works, extract other rows.

Why did you put how='inner' in the example code that's supposed to do an outer join, instead of how='outer'? Do you understand what that parameter actually means?

8-7 and 17-18 aren't in the input here, so we have no way of knowing what's wrong. Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. In the process, you might actually find the problem yourself :)

To be clear, an outer join on Rate seems to be exactly what you want, so that's why it's not clear what the problem is. On that note, if you still need help after making an MRE, write a more specific title; see [ask] for tips on that.

@wjandrea I mentioned I tried both how='outer' and how='inner'. Both didn't work as expected. I can upload the 2 files for testing if needed. I added some of the rows from both files which should be enough to test.

@d3v As I said, it's not enough to test. Please make an MRE.

@d3v I know you said you tried both, but how='inner' is definitely not what you want, and it contradicts the code comment "Merge tables on 'Rate' column with outer join".

I updated the post and added the full content from both files and the output of the script not just a minimal reproducible example. Hope you are happy now.

@d3v We don't want the full content, it's too much to go through. Please read How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

I added a minimal example with its output and desired result.

@d3v OK great, now please get rid of the bigger example.

@d3v Also, get rid of the to_excel at the end (assuming it's not relevant to the issue).

Example
Your MRE does not appear to be adequate. I changed the example somewhat. (In particular, the part where 0-7 and 7-8 coexist in df2 seems wrong to me).
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['0-4', '5-6', '7-8', '9-10', '11-13', '14-16', '17'], 'Age': ['<6.0', '6.0', '6.3', '6.6', '6.9', '7.0', '7.3']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Rate': ['0-6', '7-8', '9-10', '11-12', '13-14', '15-16', '17'], 'Grade': ['<1.0', '1', '1.2', '1.4', '1.7', '2.0', '2.3']})

Code
use IntervalIndex to set the interval and then index to the maximum value of the interval to get the result. (because the grade appears to be assigned to the maximum value in the range).
tmp = df2['Rate'].str.split('-', expand=True).ffill(axis=1).astype('int')
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(tmp[0], tmp[1], closed='both')
m = df2['Grade'].set_axis(idx)

tmp1 = df1['Rate'].str.extract('(\d+)$')[0].astype('int')
out = df1.assign(Grade=m[tmp1].values)



Thanks for trying to help not just giving instructions and talking. When I try to implement the code with the 2 Excel files I get the following:  SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d' and ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

@d3v Have you tried running it with the example I provided? If it works in the example you provided, then things are different in the example and in the excel file. Also, posting an error message and asking someone else won't solve it, because answerers will have to guess. (I'm guessing too, but I don't answer with guesses, and questioners shouldn't make answerers guess.) If you can't provide enough information, it's better to ask a question in ChatGPT than to ask to human.

I copied the data from Excel to the code and it worked. If there is a 3rd DataFrame with Rate, Percentile, and Scaled what part should I duplicate to work with 3 DataFrames? Sorry, I'm new to Python and Pandas.
